# alert recent search query

Tags: javascript, angularjs, search, cookies

So I've built an Angular application that allows you to search Github users and return some of their information. I need to add one additional feature to it. Namely, someone searches Person A. Then within five minutes of that first search, someone else also searches for Person A, I would like an alert to appear letting the user know that someone else has also searched for Person A.

I'm a bit stuck on how I would do that. Push search queries to an array and loop thru it to see if there is a match? Is this when I would use a cookie (I have little to no experience implementing a cookie)? Another strategy?

You can look at a demo at: http://www.alexmarple.com/angular-github-user-search-app/

Or look at the code at: https://github.com/alexmarple/angular-github-user-search-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies won't help you here, because if User 1 searches for Person A, then only User 1 would have a cookie that stored that information. When User 2 comes along to search for Person A, they have no idea that User 1 even exists.

You're going to need to store a list of recent searches on a server or database somewhere. That means either writing some back-end code (outside of your front-end JavaScript) which will store the list of recent searches, or finding some third-party API that will do the same thing.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for confirming that I would need to push that info to a database and query it when searching.